# Apache Flink: Why does sortPartition transformation not support KeySelector functions

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am using Apache Flink's DataSet API and found that the `sortPartition` transformation only supports position and expression keys but not key selector functions.

I use `java.util.Map` as data type which is not supported by position or expression keys. How can I use the `sortPartition` transformation on a data type such as `java.util.Map`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flink's key selector functions are syntactic sugar and can be easily manually implemented with two map functions.

- The first `MapFunction` extracts the key field and returns a `Tuple2<Key, Input>` where the key field is the extracted key and the input field is the original input (the `Map` in your case).
- The resulting data set is sorted using a position key on the first tuple field (index 0).
- The second `MapFunction` unwraps the input field from the `Tuple2<Key, Input>` tuples.

The overall code looks like:

```
DataSet<Map> input = ...
DataSet<Tuple2<Long, Map>> keyed = input.map(new KeyExtractMap());
DataSet<Tuple2<Long, Map>> sortedKeyed = keyed.sortPartition(0, Order.ASCENDING);
DataSet<Map> sorted = sortedKeyed.map(new UnwrapMap());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it's very useful, so can i use this similar way to solve the aggregate on a sort-group dataset?

for example:

```
DataSet<Map> input = ...

DataSet<<Tuple4<Long,Long,Long,Map>> keyed = input.map(new KeyExtractMap());

DataSet<<Tuple4<Long,Long,Long,Map>> sortGrouped = keyed.groupBy(0).sortGroup(1,Order.ASCENDING).sortGroup(2,Order.ASCENDING);

DataSet<Map> result = sortGrouped.map(new UnwrapMap());
```